# Email not getting send by private mail server in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

> Hello Everyone,
>    I am trying to send email through cakephp framework,but unfortunately email are not getting delivered. But when i use social email service provider such as google, outlook and rediffmail e-mail gets delivered.

My SMTP port is 465. I am using below cakephp mail()function:

```
 public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.techphant.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'xyz@abc.com',
    'password' => 'xxxxxx',
    'transport' => 'smtp',      
  );
```

Also i have tried port number 2525 and 25 but to no avail.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the log files of the mail server to see if it throws an error? Or did you try enabling debug logging?

Comment: there is no email error

Comment: have u tried this ? http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2014/01/30/cakephp-howto-send-an-email-using-a-short-tutorial/

Comment: my code is successfully running on gmail,outlook,rediffmail but my question is why email are not send in my private mail server

Comment: So everything (Google, Outlook, rediffmail) works but the smtp server at techphant.com. Maybe the problem is on the techphant.com server, not in cakephp.

Comment: i am using normal php  mail function in core php then the my sever works why ?

Comment: i know it's silly, have you checked spam? or maybe you have blocked ip list on private server

Comment: i checked into spam there is no message. and why normal mail() function work on my core php file.

Comment: Did you try with
'host' => 'smtp.techphant.com',
instead of
'host' => 'ssl://smtp.techphant.com',

Comment: i tried every thing.

Comment: If you use some basic php emailing script the error persist (just to find if the error is from CakePHP settings or is the email server settings)

Comment: Are you using this in a contact form? If yes, when the email is sent, is the sender's Email the same as the E-Mail submitted in the form? Some providers block emails, when the sender is not the same as the smtp-provider. In this case, you should use 'xyz@abc.com' as the sender.

Comment: Firts thing i am not using in contact form ,i am using in employee personality test report generation and second thing the sender email is different.

Comment: It might be more smart to focus on your private email servers log and config as the cause of the issue than the cake app if every other email server works fine.

Comment: @vikramsharma Is your private sever restricting certain ports?

Comment: It may be happening because of incorrect SMTP settings. Test sending email via non ssl than try for ssl. Also i assume you are using linux server, right ??

Comment: yes i am using linux server or i send email vai non ssl but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to send eamil with cake Email component not with mail() function.

```
$this->set(
    'content',
    '<h1>Hi </h1>
     <p>Thanks for contact us. We will respond you soon</p>
    '
);

$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
         'host' => 'ssl://smtp.techphant.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'xyz@abc.com',
        'password' => 'xxxxxx',
        'timeout' => 30,
        'client' => null
    );
    $this->Email->to = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->subject = 'Thanks for contact us';
    $this->Email->from = 'no_reply@abc.com';
    $this->Email->template = 'default';
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
    $this->Email->send();
```

Thanks..!